# Vertical alignment only partially working

Tags: html, css

would you know why my green DIV is not vertically aligned to the middle of the red DIV and how to fix this? Many thanks
http://jsfiddle.net/kAXp9/

[image]

```
.wrapper-alt {

    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 980px;
    display:table;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}   

.bigtext {
    color: #124191;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 53px;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 53px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.block-left-alt, .block-right-alt {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:30px 0;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block-left-alt {
float: left;
background: red;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:100%;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.block-right-alt {
float: left;
background: green;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:100%;
    width: 50%;
}

<div class="wrapper-alt">
<div class="block-left-alt bigtext">Pourquoi<br>faire appel<br> à nos services?</div>
<div class="block-right-alt"><ul class="bullets1-alt">
      <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Reason 1</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Reason 2</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Reason 3</li>
      </ul>
</div>
</div><!-- End Wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
float:left
```

from `.block-left-alt` and `.block-right-alt`

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/kAXp9/3/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f4vn4/)

You use float. Because of float the `<div>` gets out of the object flow, so you can't set its height to `100%`.

A tricky solution is to set the parent `<div>`'s background color to the same as the smaller `<div>`'s. So add `background: green;` to `.wrapper-alt`.